# What's the fastest way to retrieve a value from a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

What I'm trying to do now is to get a value out of 1 X 1 size tensor, and I have nearly 6000 of them.

I've tried using eval(), session() so far. The best I could think of was to change the tensor to numpy to get the value out of it. But the problem is that it's extremely slow, especially when having to deal with huge amount of data. Is there any fast way to retrieve the data from tensor?

Just for additional information, this is the part of my code where I'm trying to implement.

```
cross_IF = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(test_IF)):
  if (count % 100 == 0):
    print(count)
  count += 1
  c = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(test_IF[i], prediction_IF[i])
  element = keras.backend.eval(tf.reduce_sum(c))
  cross_IF.append(element)
```

cross_IF is the list that I'll use to stack up values from tensor 'tf.reduce_sum(c)'.
test_IF and prediction_IF are test values and prediction values.

Comment: What are the shapes of each `test_IF[i]` / `prediction_IF[i]`? You should probably concatenate all the tensors in the lists (if you cannot have the lists as tensors in the first place) and compute the `categorical_crossentropy` for all of them at the same time. You can convert the resulting NumPy array to a list later again if you want that.

Comment: I actually fixed the problem in my code. Each of them are (253, 24) and (69,24), and I had several thousand of them. The issue was that using categorical_crossentropy resulted in tensor, not numpy. So I tried to convert cross entropy to numpy format and then append that into numpy list. But instead, concatenating as a tensor form for all the cross entropies of the data and then converting that into numpy at the end made it faster. I guess it was a terrible mistake with the order of having things done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the resolution in Answer section for the benefit of community.

The issue was that using `categorical_crossentropy` resulted in `tensor`, not `numpy`.

Converting `categorical_crossentropy` to `numpy` format and then appending that into numpy list took more time.

Instead, concatenating as a `tensor` form for all the `cross entropies` of the data and then converting that into `numpy` at the **end** made it faster.